# Using postgres tuple comparison with golang SQL

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to access postgres DB using Go sql. I am trying to write the Postgres query

```
select *
from records
where (id, updated) in ( (1, timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
                         (2, timestamp '2019-01-02 00:00:00') )
```

But did not find anything documented. Is it possible to do so, I tried with string interpolation but it doesn't work

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"* is not a sufficient problem definition. Please provide the Go code that you have written, explain what you expect the result of that code to be, and include actual output / error message that that code produced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from records
where (id, updated) in ( (1,'2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp),
                         (2,'2019-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp) )
```

And if you don't want to check microsecond part, you can try this

```
select *
from records
where (id, updated::timestamp(0)) in ( (1,timestamp(0) '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
                             (2,timestamp(0) '2019-01-02 00:00:00'))
```

Or even if you don't wanna include time part, you can use this

```
 select *
 from records
 where (id, updated::date) in ( (1,date '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
                                 (2,date '2019-01-02 00:00:00'))
```